# Optimize appliances buy strategy according to discount on number of items

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

I'm going to buy some appliances from a shop and they offer the following discounts based on the number of items you buy:

- For 2 items the cheapest gets 25% off
- For 3 items the cheapest gets 55% off
- For 4 items the cheapest gets 80% off
- For 5 items the cheapest gets 99% off

I wrote a little program to try to optimize the buying strategy (for minimum price and maximum discount), for example if I need 5 items is it better to buy all 5 in one transaction or perhaps buy 2 and then 3 in two transactions?

Since I'm not happy with the attached code (it looks ugly) I was wondering what would be a better way to solve the problem (I haven't finished the final printing where I summarize all the strategies but the code seems to solve the problem anyway).

EDIT: Adding a little example to clarify the idea. Suppose we have 5 items [A, B, C, D, E]; I want to find out which is the best buying strategy to maximize save. One possible strategy is to buy (A, B) and then (C, D, E) so the strategy would be [(A, B), (C, D, E)]. Another option would be to buy the items in pairs [(A, B), (C, D), E]. The first step is to determine which of the elements to combine, for instance is (A, B) the best pair or is (A, C) the best one? Suppose that we find out that (A, D) gives the best discount, we remove it from the list of items and then consider the remaining ones [B, C, E]; these can be bought with two strategies [(B, C), E] or [(B, C, E)] in case of [(B, C), E] what is the most convenient pair: (B, C), (B, E) or (C, E)?

```py
from itertools import combinations

products = {
    'fridge': 3009,
    'washing_machine': 1449,
    'stove': 2299.99,
    'dish_washer': 1599,
    'tv': 3999,
    'oven': 1899
}


def get_discount(n_products: int) -> float:

    discounts = {
        1: 0.,
        2: .25,
        3: .55,
        4: .8,
        5: .99
    }

    return discounts[n_products]


def get_prices(in_products: list) -> list:

    prices = []

    for i in range(len(in_products)):

        prices.append(products[in_products[i]])

    return sorted(prices,)


def get_best_pair(products: dict, n_products: int) -> tuple:

    max_saved = -9999
    best_pair = None
    best_discount = None

    for pair in combinations(products.keys(), n_products):

        prices = get_prices(pair)
        discount = get_discount(n_products)

        tot_price = sum(prices)

        prices[0] -= prices[0] * discount

        tot_discounted_price = sum(prices)

        saved = tot_price - tot_discounted_price

        if saved > max_saved:

            max_saved = saved
            best_pair = pair
            best_discount = tot_discounted_price

        print(pair, prices, tot_price, tot_discounted_price, saved, max_saved)

    return best_pair, max_saved, best_discount


n_products = 5

results = {}

for i in range(2, n_products + 1):

    to_buy = products.copy()

    buy_strategy = []
    tot_saved = 0.
    tot_price = 0.

    print(f'{i}, to buy: {to_buy}, products: {products}')

    best_pair, saved, best_discount = get_best_pair(to_buy, i)

    buy_strategy.append(best_pair)
    tot_price += best_discount
    tot_saved += saved

    for product in best_pair:

        to_buy.pop(product)

    if len(to_buy) == 1:

        buy_strategy.append(*(to_buy.keys()))
        tot_price += [*to_buy.values()][0]

    print(
        f'Best combination for: {best_pair}, total discounted price: {tot_price}, tot saved: {saved}')

    left_to_buy = to_buy.copy()

    if len(left_to_buy) >= 2:

        for j in range(2, len(left_to_buy) + 1):

            left_to_buy = to_buy.copy()

            left_to_buy_strategy = buy_strategy.copy()
            left_to_buy_tot_price = tot_price
            left_to_buy_tot_saved = tot_saved

            print(f'{j}, to buy: {to_buy}, left to buy: {left_to_buy}')

            best_pair, saved, best_discount = get_best_pair(left_to_buy, j)

            left_to_buy_strategy.append(best_pair)
            left_to_buy_tot_price += best_discount
            left_to_buy_tot_saved += saved

            print(
                f'Best combination for: {best_pair}, total discounted price: {best_discount}, tot saved: {saved}')

            for product in best_pair:

                left_to_buy.pop(product)

            if len(left_to_buy) == 1:

                print(
                    f'left to buy: {left_to_buy}, price: {[*left_to_buy.values()][0]}')

                left_to_buy_strategy.append([*left_to_buy.keys()][0])
                left_to_buy_tot_price += [*left_to_buy.values()][0]

            strategy_key = 'buy_strategy' + str(i) + str(j)

            results[strategy_key] = buy_strategy

            sep = '-' * 15 + '\n'

            print(f'{sep}Buy strategy {left_to_buy_strategy}\nTot price: {left_to_buy_tot_price}\nTot saved: {left_to_buy_tot_saved}\n{sep}')
```

Comment: It might help if you posted a description of your algorithm (with pseudo code). As is, people have to reverse engineer your code to discover your algorithm. I did some of that, and here's the first thing I noticed: in the `get_best_pair` method, you're trying all possible combinations of `n` items. All you need to do is sort the list of prices descending, and apply the discount to the nth price in the list. For example, using the list of items in the code, if `n` is 3, then apply a 55% discount to the stove.

Comment: I've added a little example, I hope it clarifies the idea that I tried to write in code. I still think you need to consider all the possible combinations and that sorting is not enough.

Comment: Given items with prices `A,B,C,D,E`, and given that `A >= B >= C >= D >= E`, then the best choice for 2 items must be `A,B`. If any other pair is chosen, the discount will be applied to `C` or `D` or `E`, which will be less than or equal to the discount for `B`.